# Throwing error on adding a @Page directive

Tags: 2010, codebehind

I wanted to have a code behind file for home.aspx file for my sharepoint site. but on adding this

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" 
    Inherits="MyNamspace.MyCustomCodeBehindForHomeAspx, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
    %>
```

It is throwing this error : The dynamicmasterpagefile attribute on the page directive is not allowed in this page.

I want to know why it is throwing this error

Answer (score 0):

Check that your code-behind `MyNamspace.MyCustomCodeBehindForHomeAspx` class inherits one of the SharePoint page classes: `UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase` or its descendant. This property is declared in it.

Another option is if you'r trying to use your `aspx`-page as Site Page instead of `_layouts`-page.

Take a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537530(v=office.14).aspx) for more details about `DynamicMasterPageFile` token.